# Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa freezing after logging in as user

Tags: boot, dual-boot, login

Machine (HP, about 4 years old): https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-pavilion-15-au063nr-15-6-core-i7-6500u-12-gb-ram-1-tb-hdd-us-w2l52uaraba/

On ubuntu 20.04 and Win10 dual boot.

So to summarize: I'll go into GRUB like normal, hit Enter to boot into Ubuntu, then be brought to the login screen where I put in my password (same one used for Sudo) and login as my user on my laptop. This consistently has left me with a frozen purple screen where the mouse disappears and it just seems to get stuck. I tried to circumvent this by going to a command line and I got this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP9eS.jpg

I am no expert but this seems like some kind of loop in whatever code is running. It was not that long ago the case where I would do as I described, put in my password, get enter, and then immediately after I would hit ctrl + alt + f2 and for some reason then the purple screen wouldnt happen, but after my most recent update that's not the case. I have looked a lot online for fixes and a lot of them are graphics driver related but I dont have an Nvidia graphics cards so what gives? I've also read it could be that the user file for me is not with my associated account but how do I approach that without the command line? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, it boots up fine once, then the problem reemerges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a temporary/permanent fix, edit `/etc/default/grub`.

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Find:

```
"quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
"quiet splash pci=noaer"
```

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`

Recheck for problem.

Comment: How would I go about this if I cant access any terminals? When I try to use the hot keys for accessing that I get the imgur video I posted, and as far as I know there arent any other ways to get to a terminal without successfully booting. I see "quiet splash" is a part of parameters for default ubuntu, could it work there?

Comment: Slightly different than what you said, I had no terminal access so in GRUB, I hit e to edit the parameters for "Ubuntu" and on the row labeled "linux" I added that next to "quiet splash". Now implementing what you said should fix the problem permanently! Thanks so much